# Amazon RDS for SQL Server - allow port 3343 on AlwaysOn Multi-AZ instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS Services and I have angular dotnet core project deployed to **AWS EB**. I am also used **Amazon RDS** SQL Server Database and **AWS Cognito** for autherization.

My project was work fine, but after some times I got a message from Amazon Web Services that says

> TCP and UDP traffic on port 3343, directionally in-bound and out-bound, need to be allowed in Network ACLs of your VPC as well as in the Security Group that is attached to your Amazon RDS for SQL Server Multi-AZ instance(s).

I enable TCP and UDP traffic on port 3343  in-bound and out-bound as

**in-bound**
[image]

**out-bound**
[image]

but It didn't work. please help me, thank you.

Comment: Those screenshots show the security group rules; did you modify the network ACL ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just found the right answer from aws

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for reaching out to AWS Premium Support.
>
> From your case notes, I understand that you have received an advisory
> email which recommends opening of port 3343 to avoid unexpected
> failures in the WSFC service for RDS SQL Server Multi-AZ instances. In
> relation to this, you would like to know  if self-reference security
> group as the source will work. Please correct me if I misunderstood.
>
> To answer your query , yes Indeed, setting the source for the security
> group rules as the security group itself , should do the trick here.
> This would allow all resources associated with the security group  to
> communicate with other  associated resources.
>
> Further ,  If  you have NOT changed any default rules in ACLs, then no
> actions are needed for ACLs .

This means you can open the port 3343 to the same Security group (the sg has inbound role from itself on that port once for TCP and another for UDP)
and if your ACLs are default, no need to do anything else.

for the Security group outbound, you don't need to do anything because it already allows all traffic.